# How to say "craving for something"? (Food Related)

Tags: word-requests

I remember there is something that translates closely to "mouth itches", you say it when you want to express a craving for a certain food.

Comment: "mouth itches"? 嘴痒. However, formally it means "craving for saying something". (Anyway, I won't feel strange when anyone uses 嘴痒 to "crave for a certain food".)

Comment: No but I now remember it was 嘴 + another word.

Comment: Perhaps it would possibly be 嘴馋?

Answer (score 5):

嘴馋 should be the one. 馋 in this case means piggish or greedy for food, particularly in a situation that one is not really hungry, but just wants something to be in the mouth for chewing.

Comment: Being fond of good food and craving for a particular dish are not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just did an edit. So piggish or greedy for food is probably better.